# Why does this query of a nested object not work?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Given this `Job` object structure, where `users` is an array of user documents:

```
{
    _id: "56228b5ba851623018f88ff7",
    created: "2015-10-17T17:54:35.475Z",
    active: true,
    workOrders: [{
       startDate: "2015-10-18T05:00:00.000Z",
       name: "Test1",
       users: [{...}]
    },{
      startDate: "2015-10-20T05:00:00.000Z",
      name: "Test2",
      users: [{...}]
    }]
}
```

Why does this query work:

```
  Job.find({
    'workOrders.users._id' : userId,
    'created' : { '$gte' : new Date('10/17/2015'), '$lt': new Date('10/25/2015')},
    'active' : true
  }).exec(cb);
```

But this one does not:

```
  Job.find({
    'workOrders.users._id' : userId,
    'workOrders.startDate' : { '$gte' : new Date('10/20/2015'), '$lt': new Date('10/25/2015')},
    'active' : true
  }).exec(cb);
```

Initial thought is that `workOrder.startDate` is not of type date, but it is.

Is there some reason I cannot query the nested `workOrder` object this way? I'm just confused why I can query the `created` date property on the `Job` document, I can query the array of nested `user` documents in the `workOrders` array, but then this last query doesn't work.

Note, there are no errors thrown, it simply returns no results. Even if I expand the date range to definitely be inclusive of all dates such as 01/01/2000 to 01/01/2016 I get nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace both `startDate`'s with:

```
created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
```

...to establish whether you can add multiple dates to a document, and that your `startDate` code is not incorrect?